# Calling two stored procedures and eliminating common records

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an asp.net / c# application that interfaces with the database only through stored procedures. I have tried doing this, but no luck.

I have a stored procedure "A" that returns (for example)... recordID & Description (1:Apple; 2:Banana; 3: Tomato)

I have another stored procedure "B" that returns (for example)... recordID & Description (1:Apple; 3: Tomato; 4:Grapes; 5:Oranges)

Using these stored procedure, I need to get B minus A (meaning I need to get "Grapes", "Oranges" in my application.

I know how to call two stored procedures. But how would I store their value and eliminate the common records?

Comment: Would a third stored procedure that returns the desired results, and letting the SQL server find the remaining set (which it's good at), not be the better plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't expect those two stored procs to return large datasets then you can accomplish it in your ASP.NET code. Store the results of A in one collection (e.g. dataset) then store the results of B in another collection. And you can iterate through these two collections to eliminate duplicate records.

If, however, you do expect those stored procs to return and transmit large datasets across the wire, then you should consider doing what @Paddy suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing here is write a single procedure to achive the end result.Right code of sp1 and code sp2 as single proc and at the end calculate the your require result set.

if you have taable1 and table2 after executing first two queries, then just do

```
select * from table2
except
select * from table1
```